# APC functions usage

Tags: php, caching, apc

I have installed APC on Ubuntu recently.
The very default setting as you see

> apc.cache_by_default = 1

.
Should I use APC functions such as apc_store() and apc_fetch() in my codes?
I believe, it sounds nonsense to use these functions when cache_by_default is on, but I'm not sure.
please help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use these functions for opcode caching.
These are functions for variable caching, read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php

Answer (score 0):

APC performs two separate, and largely orthogonal, tasks when loaded:

1. Caching opcodes for PHP source files to allow them to be loaded more quickly.

   The `apc.cache_by_default` configuration setting affects whether APC performs this task.
2. Caching application data on demand.

   The `apc_store()` and `apc_fetch()` functions are used by the application to perform this task.

There is little relation between these two tasks, beyond that they use the same infrastructure to store data. (Indeed, in PHP 5.5, the two tasks are now performed by two separate extensions: `opcache` and `apcu`.) You need not use `apc_store()` and `apc_fetch()` to reap the benefits of opcode caching.